# Modifying content of a text file in C

Tags: c, fopen

I understand that in C, if I have an existing text file "test.txt", calling fopen("test.txt","w") will overwrite the existing content of "test.txt".

I am trying to find an efficient way about my problem: Suppose that I have 10 rows in test.txt with each row containing a number. test.txt can refer to the values of the inputs to a PDE solver that I have. I want to do a sensitivity analysis on the last 3 parameters, i.e. keeping the first 7 numbers in test.txt fixed, I want to try different values for the last 3 rows.  Hence, I will be writing to test.txt in a for loop but I only intend to change the values of the last 3 rows at every iteration. The append of fopen does not work for me. Is there a more efficient way to go about this than storing the first seven values in an array and having to rewrite these values in the for loop through fopen?

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to try to modify a file in-place by overwriting data in the middle of it because you'll risk overwriting later data and it's very easy to corrupt a file that way (you cannot "insert" data into a file between two bytes: you need to copy data around first, which can be very inefficient). If the file isn't big you might as well read it all into memory as a linked-list, manipulate it in-memory, and then truncate and overwrite the file.

Comment: That's true, @Dai, but in this case, the OP *intends* to lose the original data in the file tail.  That's an easier case than inserting into the middle.

Comment: **"Suppose that I have 10 rows in test.txt"** - store it in memory, perhaps in an array, and update the values in memory and do a final write when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hence, I will be writing to test.txt in a for loop but I only intend
>   to change the values of the last 3 rows at every iteration. The append
>   of fopen does not work for me. Is there a more efficient way to go
>   about this than storing the first seven values in an array and having
>   to rewrite these values in the for loop through fopen?

It seems like you're going to need to read in and store the first seven values anyway.  You can, indeed, avoid rewriting them, however.  First, open the file in read / write mode without truncation:

```
FILE *input = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
```

Read / write mode differs from append mode ("a" or "a+") in that in the former case, the file is initially positioned at the beginning and writes always go to the current file position, whereas in the latter case, the file is initially positioned at the end, and writes always go to the end.

Having opened the file in an appropriate mode, read it line by line, e.g. with `fgets()`.  After the seventh line, use `ftell()` to record the current file position for later reference.  To overwrite the last lines, use `fseek()` to return to the recorded position, and just write the new values.  This may leave junk at the end of the file, after the last line; if that will be a problem then you can overwrite the tail (e.g. with space characters).  POSIX also has `ftruncate()` which you could use to clip any tail, but that's not part of standard C.

Comment: Hmmm short of making a new file, is there a standard way to make a file shorter other than 0?

Comment: @chux, I looked, but `ftruncate()` was the closest I could find.  I was actually a bit surprised by that, so if you know of a standard C function that serves the purpose then by all means, please share.

Comment: I do not know of such. IAC, my usual approach is to first create another resultant file and delete the original.

Comment: Thanks, John. But what do you mean by "This may leave junk at the end of the file" ? Do you mean it's possible that the file will end up having 11 lines, say? This is undesirable for me.

Comment: "Leaving junk at the end" means that writing into the middle of a file does not truncate any contents that follow.  Anything you do not overwrite remains, and yes, that could be interpreted as an additional line under some circumstances.  The answer already addresses how you can avoid that when overwriting the file in-place.  The issue does not exist if you truncate and overwrite the whole file.